# sudo apt update still looks for updates in ubuntu hirsute-updates while i am using 22.04

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2DAD.png)

kindly look at the photo and help me through this.

Thank you.

Comment: You must correct your sources in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: so should i delete all entries like cdrom:[Ubuntu 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_  from sources.list?

Comment: Yes - also see here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories/

Comment: If you post your `/etc/apt/sources.list` in your question, it's possible to pin down the specific lines that are not valid.

Comment: Thank you. it worked.